# the Error is: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\StartUp\\IP.PY'

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
import shutil

original = r'C:\Users\Руслан\Desktop\HACKPROG\IP.PY'
target = r'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp'
shutil.move(original,target)
```

and I am getting the following Error:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Руслан\Desktop\HACKPROG\IP.PY", line 24, in <module>
    shutil.move(original,target)
  File "C:\Users\Руслан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 820, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\Users\Руслан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 435, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\Руслан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 264, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\StartUp\\IP.PY'
```

Comment: I would look at permissions. Look at the file permissions that the error is calling out: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\IP.PY'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't appear to have permissions to write to the Start Up folder.

You can fix this by running your Python terminal as an administrator (right click IDLE/cmd and press run as administrator).

Answer (score 0):

you can run this program in 2 ways

Method 1:
Add python to path, By editing environmental variables.

Method 2:
Open console/cmd . Direct path to python file by

```
cd C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\StartUp
```

And then after entering directory

```
python ip.py --user
```

Comment: The user was able to run the code, it just threw an error. I don't think `--user` would help as they are trying to access a system directory