# i get this error (PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\achin\\Documents\\IMDB Dataset.csv') anyone know how to fix this

Tags: python

I get this error PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\achin\Documents\IMDB Dataset.csv' and I dont know how to fix it

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\achin\Documents\IMDB Dataset.csv")
df.head(3)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [the Error is: PermissionError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied: 'C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\StartUp\\IP.PY'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66596574/the-error-is-permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied-c-programdata-m)

Comment: What happens if you try to read other csv files?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67490504/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied-error-while-loading-the-file-with

Comment: same thing happens when i try to open other csv files as well

Comment: Why did you delete the question I was helping you with? I spent a lot of time on that and it could have helped other people too. It’s kind of uncool not to even upvote a post that helped you, but to completely delete it prevents *anyone* from upvoting it and hides it so no one else can ever benefit from it either.